# We need to provide rank. Logic is whenever we have a value 'Product' then we must start the new number & all other below should follow the same rank

Tags: sql, sql-server, rank, puzzle, ranking-functions

**Sample Input:**

| ID | Vals |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Product |
| 2 | Milk |
| 3 | Butter |
| 4 | Cheese |
| 5 | Yogurt |
| 6 | Product |
| 7 | Muesli |
| 8 | Porridge |
| 9 | Product |
| 10 | Banana |

**Sample Output:**

| ID | Vals | RANK |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Product | 1 |
| 2 | Milk | 1 |
| 3 | Butter | 1 |
| 4 | Cheese | 1 |
| 5 | Yogurt | 1 |
| 6 | Product | 2 |
| 7 | Muesli | 2 |
| 8 | Porridge | 2 |
| 9 | Product | 3 |
| 10 | Banana | 3 |

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a conditional cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when vals = 'Product' then 1 else 0
           end) over (order by id) as ranking
from t
order by id;
```

Answer (score 1):

you also can use window function:

```
SELECT * , SUM(CASE WHEN Vals ='Product' THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY id) ranking 
FROM tableName
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is sorted by ID:

```sql
SELECT T.ID, 
  T.Vals, 
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM table WHERE Vals = 'Product' AND ID <= T.ID) as Rank
FROM table T
```